# Colocar num arquivo ".txt" a informação contida em linha2[0:6]

Tags: python

Colocar num arquivo ".txt" a informação contida em linha2[0:6] que é:

> ['Mem¢ria', 'f¡sica', 'total:', '7.988', 'MB']
>   ['Mem¢ria', 'f¡sica', 'dispon¡vel:', '5.277', 'MB']
>   ['Mem¢ria', 'Virtual:', 'Tamanho', 'M', 'ximo:', '9.268']
>   ['Mem¢ria', 'Virtual:', 'Dispon¡vel:', '6.094', 'MB']
>   ['Mem¢ria', 'Virtual:', 'Em', 'Uso:', '3.174', 'MB']

```
archive_sysinfo = open('saida_systeminfo.txt', 'r')
text_sysinfo = archive_sysinfo.readlines()
lista_linhas2 = []
lista_info = []

for linha2 in text_sysinfo:
    lista_linhas2.append(linha2.split())

for linha2 in lista_linhas2:
    if "Mem¢ria" in linha2:
        lista_info.append(linha2[0:6])
        print(linha2[0:6])
```

SAÍDA:

> Nome do host:                              FPAL169325
>   Nome do sistema operacional:               Microsoft Windows 8.1 Pro
>   VersÆo do sistema operacional:             6.3.9600 N/A compila‡Æo 9600
>   Fabricante do sistema operacional:         Microsoft Corporation
>   Configura‡Æo do SO:                        Esta‡Æo de trabalho membro
>   Tipo de compila‡Æo do sistema operacional: Multiprocessor Free
>   Propriet rio registrado:                   FACULDADE SENAC PORTO ALEGRE
>   Organiza‡Æo registrada:                    SENACRS
>   Identifica‡Æo do produto:                  00261-80511-41292-AA269
>   Data da instala‡Æo original:               08/01/2018, 19:29:13
>   Tempo de Inicializa‡Æo do Sistema:         26/10/2018, 20:47:23
>   Fabricante do sistema:                     LENOVO
>   Modelo do sistema:                         32092F2
>   Tipo de sistema:                           x64-based PC
>   Processador(es):                           1 processador(es) instalado(s).
>                                               [01]: Intel64 Family 6 Model 58
>   Stepping 9 GenuineIntel ~3201 Mhz
>   VersÆo do BIOS:                            LENOVO 9SKT69AUS, 17/05/2013
>   Pasta do Windows:                          C:\windows
>   Pasta do sistema:                          C:\windows\system32
>   Inicializar dispositivo:                   \Device\HarddiskVolume1
>   Localidade do sistema:                     pt-br;Portuguˆs (Brasil)
>   Localidade de entrada:                     pt-br;Portuguˆs (Brasil)
>   Fuso hor rio:                              (UTC-03:00) Bras¡lia
>   Mem¢ria f¡sica total:                      7.988 MB
>   Mem¢ria f¡sica dispon¡vel:                 5.277 MB
>   Mem¢ria Virtual: Tamanho M ximo:           9.268 MB
>   Mem¢ria Virtual: Dispon¡vel:               6.094 MB
>   Mem¢ria Virtual: Em Uso:                   3.174 MB
>   Local(is) de arquivo de pagina‡Æo:         C:\pagefile.sys
>   Dom¡nio:                                   fspoaeduc.com.br
>   Servidor de Logon:                         \CROM
>   Hotfix(es):                                165 hotfix(es) instalado(s).
>                                              [01]: KB2899189_Microsoft-Windows-CameraCodec-Package

Comment: Qual é o resultado esperado? Não está dando para entender o que você precisa.

Comment: Ler cada lista como uma linha
ex.: Mem¢ria f¡sica total 7.988 MB

Comment: Mas nao tem que colocar num arquivo? O que tem dentro de `sai_systeminfo.txt`? Você poderia editar a pergunta com essas informações?

Comment: Sim fazer o que foi mostrado e por num txt

Comment: O que tu adicionou é saída ou é o arquivo `saida_systeminfo.txt`??

Comment: É o conteúdo do saida_systeminfo.txt

Comment: Pelo que estou entendo você quer ler esse arquivo e criar outro arquivo com os dados de memória copiados para este novo arquivo. É isso?

Comment: Perfeito Fernando

Comment: Vou formular uma resposta então. Mas você precisa tentar ser mais claro ao fazer uma pergunta, você poderia já ter uma boa resposta se fosse mais fácil entender.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Não domino bem as ferramentas de edição de perguntas, por isso tento poluir o mínimo possível a tela

Comment: Homero, na [central de ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) tem dicas de como editar/formatar suas perguntas, e no [FAQ](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1084/112052) também tem bastante informação a respeito. De qq forma, mesmo se não dominar totalmente as ferramentas de edição, preocupe-se primeiro em deixar a pergunta clara (veja dicas em **[ask]** e como montar um **[mcve]**). Uma pergunta clara e mal-formatada pode ser editada por outros usuários, já uma pergunta bem formatada mas não muito clara não tem muito o que fazermos, a não ser pedir que o autor esclareça...

Comment: ok, obrigado hkotsubo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visto que você quer copiar parte de um arquivo para outro, os passos que eu faria são:

1. Abrir um arquivo para leitura ([`open('meu_arquivo', 'r')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open))
2. Abrir um arquivo para gravação ([`open('outro_arquivo', 'w')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open))
3. Ler o arquivo linha por linha `for linha in arquivo:`
4. Testar se a linha sendo lida deve ser copiada (nesse caso utilizei o [`str.startswith()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=startswith#str.startswith))
5. Escrever a linha no arquivo de saída (Ver [métodos de file-objects](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)).

Aconselho a abrir arquivos com o [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with), dessa maneira ele se encarrega de fechar o arquivo no término da leitura ou em caso de um erro ocorrer.

Abaixo um exemplo funcionando:

```
with open('saida_systeminfo.txt', 'r') as info, \
     open('resultado.txt', 'w') as txt:
    for line in info:
        if line.startswith('Memória'):
            txt.write(line)
```

<sup>[Repl.it](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/SOpt-346985-6333) com o código funcionando</sup>

---

### Edit

Visto que o conteúdo do arquivo que o AP postou contém alguns erros de *encoding*, vou apenas ressaltar que a função [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) tem um parâmetro opcional `encoding` onde você pode usar um dos [*encodings* suportados pelo python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings). Exemplos:

```
arquivo = open('meu_arquivo.txt', 'r', encoding='utf_8')
arquivo = open('meu_arquivo.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8')  # alias de 'utf_8'
arquivo = open('meu_arquivo.txt', 'r', encoding='UTF')  # alias de 'utf_8'

arquivo = open('meu_arquivo.txt', 'r', encoding='latin_1')
arquivo = open('meu_arquivo.txt', 'r', encoding='latin1')  # alias de 'latin_1'
arquivo = open('meu_arquivo.txt', 'r', encoding='iso-8859-1')  # alias de 'latin_1'

arquivo = open('meu_arquivo.txt', 'r', encoding='ascii')
arquivo = open('meu_arquivo.txt', 'r', encoding='us-ascii')  # alias de 'ascii'
arquivo = open('meu_arquivo.txt', 'r', encoding='646')  # alias de 'ascii'
```

Comment: Já ficou até formatado. E tu nem precisou por as informações numa lista

Comment: Muito obrigado mesmo Fernando!!!!

Comment: O importante é entender como funciona. Boa sorte

Comment: @Homero editei a resposta com mais uma informação que pode ajudar no teu caso.

Comment: Obrigado pelo conteúdo